# Twilio Studio Workflow data

Tags: twilio

For 2 way SMS flow - How can I get data that shows the path taken in the workflow over many instances?  I'm trying to gather stats on how well the workflow works.

Answer (score 0):

Under [Studio REST API Resources](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api#studio-rest-api-resources), the [Execution Context](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/execution-context), [Step](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/step) and [Step Context](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/step-context) should get you want you want.